# Google Sheets Query Returns All Rows in One Row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, match, google-query-language

I have a query formula setup to pull form data from another sheet in the same spreadsheet. For some reason, it is loading all the rows but in one row.

Went ahead and made a copy of my spreadsheet so the issue can be seen better

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iCIfdA7lg6DNzr6O-q7oLWeXCFgTxbrwBi4wYqR7hQw/edit?usp=sharing

How it should look is:

USD    | Migros    | 18.12

TRY    | Kumru     | 25

But is instead loading:

USD TRY    | Migros Kumru    | 18.12 25

I have another spreadsheet with an almost identical setup, but it loads the data in separate rows. Cannot figure out what is different here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually this happens when you skip 3rd query parameter. use:

```
=QUERY(DATA!A2:J4000, "SELECT F,H,G WHERE J = 'October' AND B = 'Groceries'", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I thought so too but when I put the last parameter in, it only loads the first entry

Comment: @JoshBunzel it "loads first entry" just because there is only one entry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhaEO.png

Comment: You make a good point. Was looking at the data wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `query` you can use `IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)` function:

For example if you create a new sheet and copy this formula to A1, then you'll have the range from your current sheet in the new one:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iCIfdA7lg6DNzr6O-q7oLWeXCFgTxbrwBi4wYqR7hQw/edit#gid=294335694", "A:C")
```